# Get more than 100 tweets Postman/Twitter API v2

Tags: api, twitter, pagination, postman, tweets

I'm using Postman and Twitter API v2 together, to pull data for a paper. I've loaded the "Get more than 100 tweets" library, but it's pagination doesn't seem to be working.

I keep getting this error (listed below, in bold):

```
"errors": [
    {
        "parameters": {
            "pagination_token": [
                "b26v89c19zqg8o3fpz8mukx3mf6m7ag90u7sjx2xy61kt"
            ],
            "next_token": [
                "1"
            ]
        },
        **"message": "At most one of [pagination_token, next_token] can be provided."**
    }
],
"title": "Invalid Request",
"detail": "One or more parameters to your request was invalid.",
```

Comment: What is the "Get more than 100 tweets" library?

Comment: So far as I can tell (I've got only a basic knowledge of coding) it's a library running code that automatically goes past the max no of tweets you can retrieve (100) by going through pages of tweets.

Comment: If you let us know which API you're trying to call and how you're calling it that would help. You're only showing the error but no information about the request.

Comment: > "Get more than 100 tweets" library

If you're using a framework library that does this for you, then we would need info about the library and the question is likely more about the library than the API or Postman.

Comment: Here's the pre-script:

Comment: var nextToken = pm.collectionVariables.get("nextToken");

if(nextToken){
    console.log("in if statement and next token = ", nextToken)
    let queryParam = "pagination_token=" + pm.collectionVariables.get("nextToken");
    pm.request.addQueryParams(queryParam);

Comment: Not sure if that helps. But basically I need to assign a value to nextToken, but I have no clue what to assign/how to get a value. Oh and I'm using the Twitter API V2